# PowerShell のコンソールへクリップボード経由で貼り付けると、ある文字が欠落するのはなぜ？

Tags: windows-10, powershell

**環境:**
Windows 10 + PowerShell 5.1/7.2（どちらでも）

"黒四角" を含む、`D:\work\■test`というフォルダを作成したとします。

このフォルダの文字列をクリップボードにコピー(Ctl+C)し、そのままPowerShellのコンソールへ貼り付けると `■` の文字が欠落した状態になります。

しかしながら、Windowsの「クリップボード履歴機能(Ctl+V）」経由にすると欠落なく貼り付けが完了します。

Q1. これはクリップボードコピー(Ctl+C)で保持される文字コードが、「クリップボード履歴機能」で保存される文字コードと異なるという理解でよいのでしょうか？
Q2. クリップボード履歴機能を経由する事なく `■` が欠落せずにPowerShellのコンソールへ貼り付ける対策があれば教えてください。

特に緊急を要する質問ではないのですが、今回の動作がどうも納得できなかったのでこちらに質問させてもらいました。

Comment: エディタとか何かのツールでその文字のコードを調べて追記してみてください。

Comment: utf-8  E296A0(U+25A0) となります

Comment: このIssueあたりが関係してるかもしれません。[$OutputEncoding and \[Console\]::InputEncoding are not aligned -Windows Only #14945](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14945)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q2. クリップボード履歴機能を経由する事なく ■ が欠落せずにPowerShellのコンソールへ貼り付ける対策があれば教えてください。

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>vで貼り付けるとうまくいくと思います。※私の環境ではうまくいきました。

右クリックで張り付けるとこの現象が発生するようです。

別解です。Powershellのプロパティ(オプション)のレガシーコンソールを使用するにチェックをいれ、Powershellを立ち上げ直すと、この現象が発生しなくなりました。

> Q1.
> これはクリップボードコピー(Ctl+C)で保持される文字コードが、「クリップボード履歴機能」で保存される文字コードと異なるという理解でよいのでしょうか？

私はPoweshellのコンソール(？)のバグ(ペースト時のバグ)だと考えています。クリップボードにコピーした内容は同じで、右クリックでのペーストでは問題が発生し、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>vで貼り付けると問題が発生しないので、クリップボードの内容が原因ではないと思います。

Comment: ＞＞クリップボードの内容が原因ではないと思います
納得しました。たしかにマウスの右クリック貼り付けでは欠落するのに、キーボードによるCtl+vで欠落する事なく貼り付けできました。2つの疑問何れも解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。よろしければ承認をお願いします。